# Involved into some process

Tags: grammar

would the following phrasing be correct?

> there is something **involved into** some process

Im not sure, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you after some proofreading?  Or have you just come across a typographical error for "evolved".

Comment: neither. im just learning the language

Comment: You might mean 'there is something involved in some process'; as an example: 'A carefully regulated exercise regime is involved in one successful treatment of ME'. //  ELL is our sister site, intended for people just learning the language, Vis.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Your question seems to be too basic for this community. For future questions, I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question. Please don't post the same question on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That phrasing wouldn't be correct.

You could say "there is something involved **in** some process" (as suggested in the comments). That would seem to be very vague though, presuming that you're talking about a specific process you could say "there is something involved in **the** process" or, if you're not specifying the process, "in **a** process".